# React Props Don't Have Latest Redux Store Data With Browser Forward Button

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

On **componentDidMount()**, I'm running an action to get react-router parameters from the URL using matchPath() and storing that data in the redux store.

I then use this data to execute another action based on those parameters (grabbed from the store).

This works fine if I use the internal react-router `<Link>`'s on my site - but if I use my forward and back buttons, the props in **componentDidMount()** aren't updating when the route data is saved to the redux store.

**Using Router Link tags - (console output):**

```
getRouterRouteParams action found route data:  {path: "/recipe/:recipeId/:woeType/:woe?", url: "/recipe/10054617/preset/test", isExact: true, params: {…}}

New route data saved to store.

Route data in componentDidMount from mapStateToProps:  {path: "/recipe/:recipeId/:woeType/:woe?", url: "/recipe/10054617/preset/test", isExact: true, params: {…}}
```

**Clicking "Back" then "Forward" Using Browser Buttons -  (console output):**

```
getRouterRouteParams action found route data:  {path: "/recipe/:recipeId/:woeType/:woe?", url: "/recipe/10054617/preset/test", isExact: true, params: {…}}

New route data saved to store.

Route data in componentDidMount from mapStateToProps:  {path: "/recipe-feed/:f", url: "/recipe-feed/test", isExact: true, params: {…}}
```

As you can see, the route data in componentDidMount from mapStateToProps still has data from the previous path and not the current path, despite my action's log output showing that it stored data for the current path.

#### ComponentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { routeData, location, getRouterRouteParamsAction } = this.props;

    // Update routeData in redux store before any other actions can take place - since they are dependent on accurate route data
    getRouterRouteParamsAction(location.pathname);
    console.log("Route data in componentDidMount from mapStateToProps: ", routeData);

    ... other actions here
}
```

#### The Action

Because this is a server-side rendered react app, [routes are stored](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering) in a centralized file (in case you are unfamiliar with how SSR react-router has some different config practices).

```
import routes from "../../shared/components/App/routes.js";

export const getRouterRouteParams = (path) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        let matchingRoute = routes.find(route => {
            return matchPath(path, route);
        });

        let routeData = matchPath(path, matchingRoute);
        console.log("getRouterRouteParams action found route data: ", routeData);

        dispatch({
            type: UPDATE_ROUTE_DATA,
            payload: routeData
        })

        console.log("New route data saved to store.");
    }
}
```

Is this a timing issue? Are my other componentDidMount() actions actually running before the action's dispatch() function completes, despite the seemingly correct order of the console.log outputs?

If I look in my redux-store (using the chrome extension) I can see that the correct values from the current url are in fact stored in the redux store... They're just not coming through to the props.

Is there some ***earlier*** place I could be sticking this action so I can be sure it completes storing the new route data before the other actions continue to run?

Am I supposed to override how the browser's forward and backward buttons are handled?

Answer (score 0):

Well... turns out I did not need to make my own actions / reducers to find and extract route param data using matchPath at all.

When using `withRouter`, `match` is added to props and available immediately.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;

    // Logs details about this route, including params
    console.log("Match Data: ", match);
}
```

**Relevant Docs:**

- [match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)
- [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)